# Display duration for Timer in the following format

Tags: android

I have developed a Timer component. Currently the time is being display as follows:

[image]

I want to display the time in the following manner, better to say in that specific digital format.

[image]

What changes should I make in the layout XML, or what should be my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a font for what you want in Android. I would've just drawn this directly on Canvas. Alternatively you can create one Canvas-based component per digit.

I think this blog/article about Android vector drawing on Canvas could be useful to you http://www.simonhildebrandt.com/home/tipofthedayvectorrenderinginandroid

Answer (score 0):

The format you gave is not visible, though you can do something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat stf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
System.out.println(" The time is " + stf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

This will print in a twelve hr format mentioning AM/PM.

```
SimpleDateFormat stf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
```

This will make it in 24 hrs format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... better way to represent will be how to display time in LED format in Android

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure actually but I think you will have to use images for that. This is possible using images if you are just showing hrs and min. But I think for seconds changing images will not be a practical solution.